# How to find files that match certain criteria with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, console

I created a variable `$check` to find files based on certain conditions. The code looks like this:

```
$day = (get-date).day
$year = (get-date).year
$check = (Get-ChildItem | 
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq "$day"} | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq "$year"} | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
    Format-Table LastWriteTime, Name, Length)
```

Is there a way to do it more compactly? For example use less variables etc.

Comment: What are the conditions you intend? What you are filtering out is all files updated on the current day of the month this year. So you'll get all files updated Feb 7th and Jan 7th 2013. Is that what you want?

Comment: I reformatted your code so I didn't have a horizontal scroll bar. I hope that's OK with you. Also, the (parens) around the `Get-ChildItem...` pipeline are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$check=(ls|?{$_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq "$day"}|select LastWriteTime|ft LastWriteTime, Name, Length -Auto)
```